# How to find all matches inside an array element and create a new element from every match in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm new to perl and I have an array which has the following structure:

```
cat4, cat5, cat7;

ab:12, cd:43;

cat1;

cd:51;

cat6, cat12;

ab:17;
```

What I want to do, is iterate through each element containing "cat" and then, for every match to create a new array element which also contains the data from the next element (in order to push it to another array). For example:

```
cat4 ab:12, cd:43;

cat5 ab:12, cd:43;

cat7 ab:12, cd:43;

cat1 cd:51;

cat6 ab:17;

cat12 ab:17;
```

It's not a problem for me to concatenate my current element with the next one if it contains "cat" just once. I can't do it in case it appears two or more times though.

Here is my code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array1 = ("cat4, cat5, cat7", "ab:12, cd:43", "cat1", "cd:51", "cat6, cat12", "ab:17");
my @array2;

for (my $i=0; $i<array1; i++) 
{
    my $newarrayelem;
    my $currarrayelem = $array1[$i];

    if ($currarrayelem =~ m/cat\d+/gs)
    {
       $newarrayelem = $currarrayelem." ".array1[$i+1];
       $print $newarrayelem."\n";
       $push(@array2, $newarrayelem);
    }
}

print @array2;
```

What I always get as a result is "cat4, cat5, cat7 ab:12, cd:43", "cat1 cd:51", "cat6, cat12 ab:17".

What should I do in order to get the desired result above? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the data indeed in an array to process, or is it by any chance in a file?

Comment: If the line does have `cat`, can it only have a bunch of `cat`'s or can there be other data? (What to do if there is other data in a line with `cat`s?)

Comment: The data is from a file but it's transformed into an array the way I'm showing it.  There's no other data besides `cat` in the lines.

Comment: OK, thank you -- so you'd normally process a file directly? Or do you actually want to read it into an array first for some reason?

Comment: I want to read my data into an array first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is missing some sigils, but the idea is right. It can be even simpler: instead of using `if` with the match, you can use `while` which will return the elements one by one.

```perl
for (my $i = 0; $i < $#array1; ++$i) {
    push @array2, "$1 $array1[ $i + 1 ]"
        while $array1[$i] =~ /(cat\d+)/g;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way, processing data *either* from an array or from a file (so line by line)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @data = ("cat4, cat5, cat7", "ab:12, cd:43", "cat1", "cd:51",
    "cat6, cat12", "ab:17");
my @res;

my @cats;    
# foreach my $line (<>) {   # to read from a file given on cmdline
foreach my $line (@data) { 
    chomp $line; 
    if (my @m = $line =~ /(cat[^,\s]*)/g) {
        @cats = @m; 
    }   
    elsif (@cats) { 
        push @res, "$_ $line" for @cats;
        @cats = (); 
    }   
    else { # a "stray" line, not following @cats and with no cats
        push @res, $line;
    }   
}

say for @res;
```

This prints the wanted output. It can be simplified if the data can indeed be only as shown.

Data is processed from an array, as asked.  If data comes from a file file one way is to use `while (my $line = <>)`, which reads line by line files with names given on the command line.  Or, open a file in the program and read via the filehandle.  The code's the same.